# pygame.Rect around circle

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a pong game in pygame , but i can't figure out how to but a ball circle , which i can create with pygame.draw.circle into a pygame.Rect object so i can use the colliderect function and manipulate the ball's position. 
For example, with rectangles, i can do something like this :

```
rect = pygame.Rect(255, 255, 100, 100)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, yellow, rect)
```

and then when i change the pygame.Rect object position , the drawing primitives position also changes. How can the same effect be achieved when i want to draw a circle, instead of a rectangle?
Thank you.

Comment: You want to calculate a rectangle your ball fits into?

Comment: No. The problem is that i dont know how to i get a rectangle around a drawing primitive like circle. I only know how to pass pygame.Rect object as a parameter for the pygame.draw.rect function , but not pygame.draw.circle.
I hope you understand me:d thank you.

Comment: What would drawing a circle based on a rectangle even mean? Draw a circle that intersects the corners of the rectangle? Draw a as-large-as-possible circle bounded by the rectangle? (And if so, *where* inside the rectangle?) Reinterpret the raw bytes the `Rect` in memory is made of as a `Circle` object and use nonsense parameters for the circle drawing? Crash horribly? Draw a random circle that intersects the rectangle?

Comment: The `rect` arg for `blit`ting only takes the `topleft` attribute of the `rect` that you pass in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle

"**`pygame.draw.circle`**

*Draw a circle around a point*

`pygame.draw.circle(Surface, color, pos, radius, width=0): return Rect`"

If you do:

```
circleRect = pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface, (0,0,0), (10, 10), 5)
```

Pygame will give you the rectangle that the circle is in, and you can manipulate it.

I hope that helped, and best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

something really cool-
pygame.draw.rect(screen, "red", pygame.Rect(100, 100, 100, 100),100, 100)
This draws a circle (NO CAP)

Comment: Please edit your answer to more clearly describe what it does and how it works. Look at the accepted answer for reference.